# C# Razor won't compile on random lines

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm convinced I've found a bug in the Razor engine. The following .cshtml file is snipped from a larger one, but the problem remains the same.

```
@{ string myVar = "code that does not compile"; }

@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    function foobar() {

        @if (true) {
        <text>
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            @* An arbitrary comment *@
            if ("@(myVar)" === "code that does not compile") {
                console.log("@("code that does compile")");
            }
        }
        </text>
        }
    }

</script>
}
```

As it is, this is a valid .cshtml file. Intellisense works as expected, and it compiles in a browser.

The issue is that if I remove the "arbitrary comment" line, suddenly the if statement's condition stops compiling. Intellisense no longer recognises it as Razor markup, and it no longer compiles when rendered. The Razor code in the `console.log` line, however, continues to compile as expected.

This is a fairly arbitrary example of the problem, but it's cropped up repeatedly for me in different scenarios and it's driving me mad. I keep having to insert random Razor comments to make the markup compile properly.

What's going on?

Comment: When arbitrary comment line part removed, Razor probably splits `"@("code that does not compile")"` as `"@("`, `code that does not compile` & `")"`, which seems recognized as invalid JS syntax in Intellisense. Instead, try to assign `code that does not compile` part into a JS variable (e.g. `var code = @("code that does not compile")`and access that variable inside `for` loop, which it is a JS loop.

Comment: I couldn't find the solution to this, but found some alternative workarounds to adding an arbitrary comment. You could put an extra space after the bracket in the if statement `if ( "@("code that...` or remove the `<text>` tags and prefix every line with `@:`

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I could replace the string literal with a C# variable like so - `"@(myVar)"` or simply `"@myVar"` - and it still wouldn't compile, even though it's now valid JS syntax. It truly just seems to be a weird case where the Razor parser breaks on that line for some reason.

Comment: @James Yeah, there's a bunch of ways you could restructure your code to work around the glitch, but it's still an inconvenience, sometimes a major one. Replacing the `<text>` tags with `@:` is feasible in this scenario, but not if the JS was 100 lines long, for instance.